# How do I configure my Nikon D3300 so technical info doesn't pop up after every shot?

Tags: camera-settings, nikon-d3300

I own a Nikon d3300, and suddenly every time I take a shot, information about the picture pops up. How do I remove this?

Comment: What do you _want_ to happen? Just the image review with no numbers or other information, or nothing on the screen at all?

Answer (score 1):

The camera shows you the last set of info that was selected. When you see it again, press the down or up direction on the 4-way controller until you see the view you want. The next time you shoot, that is what you will see.

On Nikon entry-level DSLRs you can even disable this completely in the Playback menu by changing the *Playback Display Options*. Just unselect the ones you do not want to see (use the left or right direction), then press OK to confirm. After that, up or down will only cycle through the remaining options.